# connection between mysql and android

Tags: php, android

I tried try this code"

```
private static String url_create_product = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/create_product.php";


class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String name = inputName.getText().toString();
        String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
        String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
}
```

I got error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
Process: com.example.androidhive, PID: 2173
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(NewProductActivity.java:99)
at com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(NewProductActivity.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)  
... 3 more
android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b4d44420 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-169,88} that was originally added here
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:346)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
at com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity$CreateNewProduct.onPreExecute(NewProductActivity.java:76)
at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
at com.example.androidhive.NewProductActivity$1.onClick(NewProductActivity.java:56)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

my php file is in `C:/wamp/www/android_connect/create_product.php.htm` How pass the url?

Comment: What is the line 99 of your NewProductActivity file?

Comment: Downvoting because even a code shown, there's no actual effort shown regarding the problem solving. It seems like "I tried `echo string string`, I get this error: `syntax error, unexpected 'string' (T_STRING)`, my php file is '/home/vhosts/myhost/myphpfile.php' how fix problem"

Answer (score 0):

Start new activity on onPostExecute method

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();

 try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
    }
```

onPostExecute method is called after the background computation finishes.The result of background process are passed in this method as parameters.And now you can dismiss progress dialog ,to indicate that background task is completed. You cant handle your View in doInBackground method.Because doInBackground method is non-UI thread.

Comment: why i start new activity on onPostExecute  method

Comment: same error, i try this "http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/" for connecting mysql. but i can't get a output, anil u have a solution

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46149/discussion-between-123456-and-anil-bhatiya)

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
                if (file_url != null){
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

try this and say whats the response

Answer (score 0):

I might be late, but this might save some time for someone else in need, in future..

The problem is, if you are using the latest version of WampServer(2.5), uninstall it.. and instead install WampServer 2.4 version for that specific example.

It should work. That's what worked for me.
Hope this helps someone ! cheers..

P.S.
Even i don't know why it doesn't work on the later versions..hope someone enlightens us on that.. Thanks.